# Can "i.e." refer to the whole sentence?

Tags: grammar

I've seen sentences like this one in which "i.e." refers to a word or a phrase:

> I like **citrus fruits**, i.e. the juicy, edible fruits with leathery,
>   aromatic rinds of any of numerous tropical, usually thorny shrubs or
>   trees of the genus Citrus.
>   (http://dictionary.reference.com)

I wonder if it can restate the whole sentence, especially in this context:

> Nowadays, many students tend to start their tasks as close to the deadline as possible, i.e., "Student Syndrome".

Here I mean:

> Student Syndrome is a phenomenon in which the student is likely to begin his or her tasks as late as possible.

Comment: It can refer to anything you want to describe in other words.

Comment: I think I find your second example "awkward".  Would likely read better with just a dash instead of "ie".

Comment: Hello Ehsan, good question. I notice that though you'd like to upvote Lachlan's answer you lack sufficient rep to do so. One way to acquire sufficient rep would be to ask an interesting question and wait a little while, allowing as many ELU members to get a look at your OP and maybe upvote you, as I have, or contribute commentary or an answer. When you quickly make an official selection you disincentivize, to some extent, broader community participation in your post. That, in turn, will likely reduce the possible reps your OP accrues. Oh yeah, +1

Comment: @LittleEva good piece of advice! I'll take it!

Comment: ie means 'in other words' and needs to lead on to a balanced restatement / explanation. Here, 'Many students tend to do X' isn't balanced by 'Student Syndrome'.

Comment: Look at the 2nd answer here - the (if I may say so) brilliant exposition on 
contractions from Latin. You've got it upside down. It should be: "*Student 
Syndrome*", **ie**. Nowadays, many students tend to start their tasks as close 
to the deadline as possible **or** *Nowadays the student is likely to begin his 
or her tasks as late as possible*, **eg**. "Student Syndrome" (I'm keeping well 
clear of the "nowadays" issue) dmk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence (*"Nowadays, .."*) would seem unsatisfactory to most readers, because *"i.e."* indicates that you are going to *explain* or *rephrase* the term or the phrase that precedes it to help the reader understand something. Someone who reads *"i.e."* is probably geared up cognitively for an expansion rather than a reduction, and might feel let down by the two little words *"student syndrome"*. What's more, if the reader isn't already familiar with the term, it just doesn't work as as explanation. I'd suggest something along the lines of the following.

> *Nowadays, so many students start their tasks as close to the deadline as possible that this behavior has been termed "student syndrome"*.

Comment: Thanks! That's just what I needed. I will vote up as soon as I get 15 rep :)

Comment: For the latter example, the more appropriate usage for *i.e* (= *id est,* "that is") would be something like "Candice suffers from *student syndrome,* i.e., a tendency to start tasks as close to the deadline as possible."

Answer (score 1):

There are two Latin contractions which have entered the English language between which it is difficult to differentiate:

**ie**: or "id est", which translates (roughly) to "in other words"

and

**eg**: or "exemplii gratia", which comes out as "example given"

So,

"Australia is home to the marsupials, **ie**. a group of mammals in which the female lacks a placenta and the young are carried and suckled in an external pouch on the mother's body until mature"

or

"Australia is home to the marsupials, **eg**. the kangaroo."

OK, it's not easy but the difference is that 
"Australia is home to the marsupials, **in other words**, a group of mammals in which the female lacks a placenta & the young are carried and suckled in an external pouch on the mother's body until mature."

Also, Australia is home to the marsupials, **and, the example I am giving (of a marsupial) is**. the kangaroo. (But there are others: the Koala & the wallaby).

Hope this helps

dmk

Comment: As an ex-publisher, I feel it would be remiss of me not to acknowledge The Chambers Dictionary as providing the definition of "marsupial" in the **ie** example.